# Buttons appear transparent when I set a background image. I want Solid buttons

Tags: android

When using a small gif to be used as a background tile for a layout, I have found that my buttons appear transparent which is NOT what I want and I have not set any transparency parameters either (unless the background gif is transparent?)

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundrepeat"
    >
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    />
   </ScrollView>
<Button android:text="Connect To Phidget" android:id="@+id/connect_button" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
   android:background="@null"
    ></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the drawable tile is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/original10" 
    android:tileMode="repeat"
     />
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: It's recommended to use png. Can't you convert it?

Comment: Agreed, GIF is a proprietary format and should be avoided.

Comment: I tried a png and it's still the same. Surly there must be an XML attribute to set transparency/alpha?

Comment: REsolved it! I forgot the button is disabled and android must alter the transparency!

Answer (score 3):

As per the Android developer documentation, it is quite [clearly stated](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) that using GIF images is *discouraged*.

While they don't elaborate on the reason - I'm assuming due to its multi-layering nature. But I've played with the GIF images and encountered unwanted errors similar to yours.

So I'd suggest you to export your GIF image to a PNG and try with that. You can use any tool like Gimp or IrfanViewer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Than remove the tag:

```
android:background="@null"
```

That makes it transparent in the way you describe it.

Comment: Sorry, left that in by mistake. Have already taken that out as I had put it in to try and tinker

Answer (score 0):

add this tag in button

```
android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
```

Comment: That results in a solid black box. I want the default button style with no transparency. I can't believe it's this hard to do!